# How to completely remove zsh (oh-my-zsh) from Mac M1 (MacOS Monterey)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I have tried to run:

```
uninstall_oh_my_zsh
```

but i get a message stating that: **-bash: uninstall_oh_my_zsh: command not found**

Other commands i have tried are:

```
chmod +x ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh
```

I get a response stating that: **No such file or directory**

sh ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh

Ran:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

To change default terminal from **/bin/zsh** to **/bin/bash**

I also tried:

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
cp ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

None of them have worked thus far, when i open my terminal. I get a message stating that:
**The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`**

Comment: If you have oh-my-zsh, the right way to uninstall it is to run the command: `uninstall_oh_my_zsh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have Oh My Zsh (a set of configuration files for `zsh` and a way to manage them) installed in the first place.

The warning is coming from `/bin/bash` itself; it's hard-coded into the executable supplied by macOS.

```
$ strings /bin/bash | grep "default interactive shell"
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
```

Though they don't say so, I suspect the warning is there because they plan to remove `bash` from future versions of macOS entirely. They stopped providing newer versions of `bash` years ago.

Your default shell is *already* `/bin/bash`; the warning is recommending that you switch *to* `/bin/zsh`.

You can continue to use `bash`, though I recommend installing a newer version (3.2 is *old*) using something like Homebrew, then changing your login shell to the new version.

However, unless you are really committed to using `bash`, I suggest given `zsh` a try.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks. Guess i will stick to my zsh after all

Comment: Useful the comment may be, it does not answer the question

Comment: @PimvanderHeijden How do you propose uninstalling a package that isn't installed in the first place? The answer provided in a comment on the question would be applicable to people who *do* have `oh-my-zsh` installed, but would not solve the problem/misunderstanding laid out in the text of the question, regardless of what the *title* is asking.

Comment: Sure you have helped the person posing the question. But this post is about uninstalling zsh and that's what people coming could be looking for, since it's suggested in the title. I, for example, want to do a clean install, since something is wrong with my current installation.